How to drag and reorder list in Jetpack Compose?
Can someone help me correct the logic of reordering list. I believe the moveTodo function in viewmodel is not working properly. Reordering is working but not like how it should.
Project Structure
..db
....ToDoDAO
....ToDoDB
..drag
....DragDropList
....DragDropListExtensions
....DragDropListState
..ViewModel
..ListPage
Dao
interface ToDoDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM todolist")
    fun getAllData() : Flow<List<toDoList>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM toDoList WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1")
    suspend fun getDataById(id: Int): toDoList?

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertData(toDoList: toDoList)

    @Query("DELETE FROM todolist WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun deleteData(id : Int)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateData(todo: toDoList)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM todoList")
    fun getAllDataSync(): List<toDoList>

    @Query("SELECT MAX(position) FROM todoList")
    suspend fun getMaxPosition(): Int?

}

Database and entity:
@Database(entities = [toDoList::class], version = 2)
@TypeConverters(typeConverters::class)
abstract class ToDoDB : RoomDatabase() {

    companion object{
        const val Name = "Todo_Database"
    }

    abstract fun getDao(): ToDoDAO

}

@Entity
data class toDoList(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var date: Date,
    var title: String,
    var position: Int
)

DragDropList:

    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Composable
    fun DragDropList(
        items: List<toDoList>, // Changed to List<toDoList> since LazyColumn expects a list
        onMove: (Int, Int) -> Unit,
        viewModel: TodoViewModel,
        // onDelete: (Int) -> Unit, // Added item id to onDelete for better handling
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        var overScrollJob by remember { mutableStateOf<Job?>(null) }
        val dragDropListState = rememberDragDropListState(onMove = onMove)
    
        var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        var currentItem by remember { mutableStateOf<toDoList?>(null) } // Track current item for editing
        var textInput by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
        val context = LocalContext.current
    
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = modifier
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress(
                        onDrag = { change, offset ->
                            change.consume()
                            dragDropListState.onDrag(offset = offset)
    
    
                            if (overScrollJob?.isActive == true)
                                return@detectDragGesturesAfterLongPress
    
                            dragDropListState
                                .checkForScroll()
                                .takeIf { it != 0f }
                                ?.let {
                                    overScrollJob = scope.launch {
                                        dragDropListState.lazyListState.scrollBy(it)
                                    }
                                } ?: kotlin.run { overScrollJob?.cancel() }
    
                        },
                        onDragStart = {
                            dragDropListState.onDragStart(it)
                        },
                        onDragEnd = {
                            Log.d("DragDropList", "ended")
                            dragDropListState.onDraginterrupted() },
                        onDragCancel = { dragDropListState.onDraginterrupted() }
                    )
                }
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(all = 10.dp),
            state = dragDropListState.lazyListState
        ) {
            itemsIndexed(items) { index: Int, item: toDoList ->
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .composed {
                            val offsetOrNull = dragDropListState.elementDisplacement.takeIf {
                                index == dragDropListState.currentIndexOfDraggedItem
                            }
                            Modifier.graphicsLayer {
                                translationY = offsetOrNull ?: 0f
                            }
                        }
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(8.dp)
                        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
                        .animateItemPlacement()
                        .padding(16.dp),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d", Locale.ENGLISH).format(item.date),
                            fontSize = 12.sp,
                            color = Color.LightGray
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:aa", Locale.ENGLISH).format(item.date),
                            fontSize = 12.sp,
                            color = Color.LightGray
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = item.title,
                            fontSize = 20.sp,
                            color = Color.White
                        )
                    }
    
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        currentItem = item
                        textInput = TextFieldValue(item.title)
                        showDialog = true
                    }) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_edit_24),
                            contentDescription = "Edit",
                            tint = Color.White
                        )
                    }
    
                    IconButton(onClick = { viewModel.deleteTodo(item.id) }) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_delete_24),
                            contentDescription = "Delete",
                            tint = Color.White
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        // Dialog for editing task
        if (showDialog && currentItem != null) {
            AlertDialog(
                onDismissRequest = { showDialog = false },
                title = { Text(text = "Edit Task") },
                text = {
                    // Text input field inside the dialog
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        value = textInput,
                        onValueChange = { newValue -> textInput = newValue },
                        placeholder = { Text("Enter Text") },
                        label = { Text("Enter Text") },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth() // Make the text field fill the dialog width
                    )
                },
                confirmButton = {
                    TextButton(
                        onClick = {
                            // Action on Confirm button
                            // Handle the input data (e.g., save or process the text)
                            if (textInput.text.isNotEmpty()) {
                                currentItem?.let {
                                    viewModel.updateTodo(it.id, textInput.text)
                                }
                                showDialog = false
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter some text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                        }
                    ) {
                        Text("Confirm")
                    }
                },
                dismissButton = {
                    TextButton(
                        onClick = { showDialog = false }
                    ) {
                        Text("Dismiss")
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }


DragDropListExtensions
fun LazyListState.getVisibleItemInfoFor(absoluteIndex: Int): LazyListItemInfo? {
    return this.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.getOrNull(absoluteIndex - this.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.first().index)
}

val LazyListItemInfo.offsetEnd: Int
    get() = this.offset + this.size

fun <T> MutableList<T>.move(from: Int, to: Int) {
    if (from == to) return
    val element = this.removeAt(from) ?: return
    this.add(to, element)

}

DragDropListState
@Composable
fun rememberDragDropListState(
    lazyListState: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(),
    onMove: (Int, Int) -> Unit
): DragDropListState {
    return remember(lazyListState) {
        DragDropListState(lazyListState, onMove)
    }
}

class DragDropListState(
    val lazyListState: LazyListState,
    private var onMove: (Int, Int) -> Unit
){
    var draggedDistance by mutableStateOf(0f)
    var initiallyDraggedElement by mutableStateOf<LazyListItemInfo?>(null)
    var currentIndexOfDraggedItem by mutableStateOf<Int?>(null)
    val initialOffsets: Pair<Int, Int>?
        get() = initiallyDraggedElement?.let {
            Pair(it.offset, it.offsetEnd)
        }

    val elementDisplacement: Float?
        get() = currentIndexOfDraggedItem
            ?.let { draggedIndex ->
                // Find the visible item corresponding to the dragged index
                lazyListState.getVisibleItemInfoFor(absoluteIndex = draggedIndex)
//                lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.find { it.index == draggedIndex }
            }
            ?.let { visibleItem -> (initiallyDraggedElement?.offset ?: 0f).toFloat() + draggedDistance - visibleItem.offset
//                // Calculate the displacement based on the initial offset and dragged distance
//                val initialOffset = (initiallyDraggedElement?.offset ?: 0f).toFloat()
//                val currentOffset = visibleItem.offset.toFloat()
//
//                // Return the displacement as the difference between initial and current offsets
//                initialOffset + draggedDistance - currentOffset
            }

    val currentElement: LazyListItemInfo?
        get() = currentIndexOfDraggedItem?.let { draggedIndex ->
            // Find the visible item corresponding to the dragged index
            lazyListState.getVisibleItemInfoFor(absoluteIndex = draggedIndex)
            //lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.find { it.index == draggedIndex }
        }

    var overScrollJob by mutableStateOf<Job?>(null)

    fun onDragStart(offset: Offset) {

        lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            .firstOrNull { item ->
                // Convert y offset to an Int and check if it is within the bounds of this item's vertical position
                offset.y.toInt() in item.offset..(item.offset + item.size)
            }?.also {
                currentIndexOfDraggedItem = it.index
                initiallyDraggedElement = it
            }
    }

    fun onDraginterrupted(){
        draggedDistance = 0f
        currentIndexOfDraggedItem = null
        initiallyDraggedElement = null
        overScrollJob?.cancel()
    }

    fun onDrag(offset: Offset) {
        draggedDistance += offset.y

        initialOffsets?.let { (topOffset, bottomOffset) ->
            val startOffset = topOffset + draggedDistance
            val endOffset = bottomOffset + draggedDistance

            currentElement?.let { hoveredElement ->
                lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
                    .filterNot { item ->
                        item.offsetEnd < startOffset || item.offset > endOffset || hoveredElement.index == item.index
                    }
                    .firstOrNull { item ->
                        val delta = startOffset - hoveredElement.offset
                        when {
                            delta > 0 -> (endOffset > item.offsetEnd)
                            else -> (startOffset < item.offset)
                        }
                    }?.also { item ->
                        currentIndexOfDraggedItem?.let { current ->
                            onMove.invoke(current, item.index)
                        }
                        currentIndexOfDraggedItem = item.index
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    fun checkForScroll(): Float{
        return initiallyDraggedElement?.let {
            val startOffset = it.offset + draggedDistance
            val endOffset = it.offsetEnd + draggedDistance

            return@let when {
                draggedDistance > 0 -> (endOffset - lazyListState.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset).takeIf {  diff ->
                    diff > 0
                }
                draggedDistance > 0 -> (endOffset - lazyListState.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset).takeIf { diff ->
                    diff < 0
                }
                else -> null
            }
        } ?: 0f
    }



}

ViewModel
class TodoViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val todoDao = MainApp.todoDatabase.getDao()


    // Use MutableStateFlow for handling the list state
    private val _todoList = MutableStateFlow<List<toDoList>>(emptyList())
    val todoList: StateFlow<List<toDoList>> = _todoList.asStateFlow()

    // Use StateFlow to expose Flow as state-driven data to the UI
    init {
        // Collect initial data from the database
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _todoList.value = todoDao.getAllDataSync()
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun addTodo(title : String){
        // Creating separate thread for DB operation
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

            val maxPosition = todoDao.getMaxPosition() ?: -1

            todoDao.insertData(toDoList( title = title, date = Date.from(Instant.now()), position = maxPosition + 1 ) )
            _todoList.value = todoDao.getAllDataSync()
        }
    }

    fun deleteTodo(id : Int){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            todoDao.deleteData(id)
            _todoList.value = todoDao.getAllDataSync()
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun updateTodo(id: Int, newTitle: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val todo = todoDao.getDataById(id)
            if (todo != null) {
                val updatedTodo = todo.copy(title = newTitle, date = Date.from(Instant.now()))
                todoDao.updateData(updatedTodo)

                // Instead of fetching all todos again, update the specific item in the current state
                _todoList.value = _todoList.value.map {
                    if (it.id == id) updatedTodo else it
                }
            }
        }


    }

    fun moveTodo(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // Fetch the current list of todos
            val todos = todoDao.getAllDataSync()

            // Ensure that both indices are within the valid range
            if (fromIndex in todos.indices && toIndex in todos.indices) {
                // Create a mutable copy of the current list
                val reorderedList = todos.toMutableList()

                // Hold the item to be moved
                val movedTodo = reorderedList[fromIndex]

                // Remove the item from its original position
                reorderedList.removeAt(fromIndex)

                // Insert it at the new position
                reorderedList.add(toIndex, movedTodo)

                // Update the positions for all items in the reordered list
                // Ensure to update all items' positions based on their new indices
                for (index in reorderedList.indices) {
                    // Create a new todo with the updated position
                    val updatedTodo = reorderedList[index].copy(position = index)

                    // Update the database with the new position
                    if (updatedTodo.position != todos[index].position) {
                        todoDao.updateData(updatedTodo)
                    }
                }

                // Update the state with the new order
                _todoList.value = reorderedList
            } else {
                // Log an error if indices are out of range
                Log.e("TodoViewModel", "Invalid indices: fromIndex = $fromIndex, toIndex = $toIndex")
            }
        }
    }

}

ListsPage (actual UI)
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Composable
fun TodoListPage(viewModel: TodoViewModel){

    val todoList by viewModel.todoList.collectAsState()
    var inputText by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val context = LocalContext.current


    Scaffold(

        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text("To-Do List", color = Color.White) },
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Purple40
                )
            )
        },


        content ={ it ->

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .padding(it)
                ) {

                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(8.dp),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                    ) {
                        OutlinedTextField(
                            modifier= Modifier.weight(2f),
                            value = inputText,
                            onValueChange = {
                                inputText = it
                            },
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
                            )
                        Button(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                            onClick = {
                            if(inputText.isNotEmpty()){
                                viewModel.addTodo(inputText)
                                inputText = ""
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter some text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                        }

                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Add", color = Color.White)
                        }
                    }

                    DragDropList(items = todoList, onMove = { fromIndex, toIndex -> viewModel.moveTodo(fromIndex, toIndex)} , viewModel = viewModel)


                }

        }
    )
}

I want the reordering to work as it is supposed to work. All the changes are correctly reflected in backend but not shown in that manner in the UI.

Had to sort list everytime according to position when an update was made. Updated moveTodo function is
    fun moveTodo(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val todos = todoDao.getAllDataSync()

        if (fromIndex in todos.indices && toIndex in todos.indices) {
            val re = todos.toMutableList()
            val reorderedList = re.sortedBy { it.position }.toMutableList()

            val fromTodo = reorderedList[fromIndex]
            val toTodo = reorderedList[toIndex]

            val tempPosition = fromTodo.position
            fromTodo.position = toTodo.position
            toTodo.position = tempPosition

            todoDao.updateData(fromTodo)
            todoDao.updateData(toTodo)

            reorderedList[fromIndex] = fromTodo
            reorderedList[toIndex] = toTodo

            _todoList.value = reorderedList

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                Log.d("TodoViewModel", "Updated todoList: ${todos} ")
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("TodoViewModel", "Invalid indices: fromIndex = $fromIndex, toIndex = $toIndex")
        }
    }
}

